# Biased coin flip

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a code that takes the probability of a biased coin with range between 0 and 1, as input from the user and tests a number of coin ﬂips where p is the probability of the ﬂip resulting in a result of heads.Here's what I have so far:

```
import random
i = 0
for i in range(3):
    i = i + 1
#I want to call biasedflip function here

p = input("Enter probability:")
def biasedflip():
    if random.random() < p:
        print("Heads")
    else:
        print("Tails")
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: There are a lot of syntax errors. You may want to start with a basic Python tutorial first before attempting something like what you are trying to do.

Comment: My question is what's the appropriate code to generate the biased coin flip

Comment: You could do a really dirty example with getting a random number from a large range say 1 - 100 and include a statement that if say 1 - 60 = heads 61 - 100 = tails... thats biased and simple...

Comment: Please at least attempt to do a Google search before asking a new question.

Comment: I've actually looked through google but none of them give the desired outcome im looking for and the i've looked through the link you mentioned but that code doesn't run.

Comment: That code works perfectly.

Comment: I just tried the code in the duplicate question and it ran fine in both python 2 and 3

Comment: I may have formatted it incorrectly or made some other error could you please provide me the entire code, so that i copy paste it into idle and try ?

Answer (score 1):

*("This is answer is based on the latest version of python, so make sure you are using 3.5.x otherwise some notation may not work properly")*

Firstly your function "biasedflip" needs brackets after the name and before the colon for proper notation
So it should be:

```
def biasedflip():
```

Secondly to make it easier to change the probability to use a range of 1-100 so that you can avoid decimals to make it easier to follow through
So when they input (p) it should be 1-100 and that will decide your fail value which is where if it is equal to or higher than it displays Tails
You can produce this by using:

```
random.randint(1,100)
```

^
This generates a random integer using an inclusive range of 1-100 rather than your random.random() which is not going to function.

After editing your random statement you then just change your if statement to look like:

```
if random.randint(1,100) < Probability:

   print("Heads")

else:

   print("Tails")
```

When running the program you should also set the number of flips to be an input so you can test it multiple times rather than editing the code so add a new variable called NumberOfTrials:

```
NumberOfTrials = int(input("How many times do you wish to flip the coin? "))
```

^
This converts their input into an integer so it can be used in the range function

With the input for your probability python takes standard inputs to be strings so you need to convert the input into an integer which you can do by using:

```
Probability = int(input("Enter a probability for heads between 1 and 100"))
```

^This will convert the input straight to an integer and assign it to Probability, I have changed the variable name from "p" to "Probability" so the use is clearly defined

At this stage from the top of your program it should look like:

```
import random

i = 0
Probability = int(input("Enter a probability for heads between 1 and 100: "))
NumberOfTrials = int(input("How many times do you wish to flip the coin? "))

def biasedflip():

   if random.randint(1,100) < Probability:

      print("Heads")

   else:

      print("Tails")
```

Next we will add another 2 new variables so you can store the totals for Heads and Tails separately to allow for later reference:

```
TotalHeads = 0
TotalTails = 0
```

^These are starting as 0 and will be defined before the function so they are not reset every time we call it, only every time the program is reset

The final stage is adding a loop and then displaying the total number of heads and tails. This can be done using a while loop and a count variable of (i) which you have already defined before and set to 0. This will something like:

```
while i < NumberOfTrials:
   biasedflip()
   i += 1
```

^After adding this loop we need to modify our function so that the TotalHeads and TotalTails variables are increased inside the function rather than complicating it and editing inside and outside of the function. This just involves adding a **TotalHeads += 1** beneath the Print("Heads") statement and a **TotalTails += 1** beneath the Print("Tails") statement. An important note is as we have set the variables outside of the function we have to had 2 global statements to call the variables in to the function to allow editing, these statements just look like **global TotalHeads** and **global TotalTails** and should be the first commands of the function.

We also need to add a final print command at the end just displaying the totals so our final result should look like:

```
import random

TotalHeads = 0
TotalTails = 0
i = 0
Probability = int(input("Enter a probability for heads between 1 and 100: "))
NumberOfTrials = int(input("How many times do you wish to flip the coin? "))

def biasedflip():

   global TotalTails
   global TotalHeads

   if random.randint(1,100) < Probability:

      print("Heads")
      TotalHeads += 1

   else:

      print("Tails")
      TotalTails += 1

while i < NumberOfTrials:
   biasedflip()
   i += 1

print("After {0} flips there was {1} Head(s) and {2} Tail(s)".format(NumberOfTrials,TotalHeads,TotalTails))
```

^You can see on that final command I have used **.format** which means you can use placeholder {0} values to fill with variables such as NumberOfTrials so you can make sentences editable through the program and look neater when printed

Also for calling functions the general format is **FunctionName()** but when defining it should be **def FunctionName():**